# MySQL - Fetch rows where a field value is less than 5 chars

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to fetch all the rows where the 'zip' field is less than 5 characters. How can I achieve this using only SQL? I google'd first, but only found info on CHAR_LENGTH().

ie, psudeo code: SELECT * FROM users WHERE STRLEN(zip_code) < 5

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For MySQL you would use the LENGTH() function ie.

```
select * from users where length(zip_code) < 5
```

Refer to the docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length for more information.

Answer (score 12):

[`CHAR_LENGTH(zip_code) < 5`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)

Comment: Do note the difference between `LENGTH()` and `CHAR_LENGTH()`; `LENGTH()` gives the length in bytes, whereas `CHAR_LENGTH()` gives the length in characters. This doesn't matter with an 8-bit encoding, but with UTF-8 and the like they can give different results.

Answer (score 2):

You can use length

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LENGTH(myfield) < 5;
```

Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length) out for more info.

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching for bad zip codes then char_length(zip_code) < 5 is a start, but
it will still pass invalid ZIP codes.

use SELECT * from users where char_length(zip_code) < 5 OR zip_code NOT REGEXP '^([0-9]{5})$'

The regexp part basically searches for zip_codes where the first 5 characters are not numbers between 0-9

Have Fun

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LENGTH(zip) <= 5;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.